# How to make use of Debian Installer's tabs which appeared in Stretch?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, installer

Debian Installer network install console (over ssh) in Stretch differs from that of Jessie and earlier. It has additional black "menu" line above the screen, which shows four "tabs" and a clock. These "tabs" are "(1*installer)", "2 shell", "3 shell", "4- log".

I remember them from "local" installer, where installer is on tty1, shells are on tty2 and tty3 and log is on tty4. It seems the Debian team added similar functionality to the ssh network install console.

However, I can't find any information on how to use them. How can I switch these "tabs" (from within ssh install session)?

[image: ssh installer screenshotenter image description here]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Strangely I couldn't find any reference about this feature, but the whole remote ssh installer menu is actually running inside a screen, as this line can confirm (later, once the solution is already found):

```
~ # ps |grep screen|grep -v grep
 4356 root     11432 S    /usr/bin/screen -U sh -c printf "\033k%s\033\\" installer ; /lib/debian-installer/menu
 4357 root     12256 S    {screen} /usr/bin/SCREEN -U sh -c printf "\033k%s\033\\" installer ; /lib/debian-installer/menu
```

So the usual [screen default key bindings](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/screen/screen.1.en.html#DEFAULT_KEY_BINDINGS), all starting with the character <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, apply. Here are the two most useful navigation commands, with those sequences:

> C-a n
>
> C-a C-n   (next)
>       Switch to the next window.

and

> C-a p
>
> C-a C-p   (prev)
>       Switch to the previous window (opposite of C-a n).

Which will allow to cycle through the installer, the two available busybox, and the logs.

I hope there are easy methods to input <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> in non Latin keyboards, or that the language/keyboard selection already took care of changing the defaults.